# Argument labels '(withReadPermission:, from:, handler:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: facebook-graph-api, swift3

Just converted a project to Swift 3 and can't figure out the following error. And I don't know where is the mistake with message:

> Argument labels '(withReadPermission:, from:, handler:)' do not match
>   any available overloads

```
FBManager.shared.logIn(
    withReadPermission: ["public_profile", "email"],
    from: self,
    handler: { (result, error) in

        if (error == nil) {
            elf.fbLoginSuccess = true
        }
```

Comment: Just converted a project to Swift 3 and can't figure out the where is the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to update your pods to swift 3+ branch as it introduced argument labels (_) , and use this

```
let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()

facebookLogin.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile","email", "user_friends"], from:self, handler:
{

      (facebookResult, facebookError) -> Void in
})
```